# Как вывести количество упоминаний в соц.сетях?

Tags: twitter, facebook, соцсети, вконтакте

Нужно вывести количество лайков (FB/ВК), твитов, +1 по нужному запросу на DLE. Например, есть новость про Mercedes-Benz C230 и мне нужно вывести количество (просто цифру) упоминаний этого запроса (который прописывается в доп.поле движка) в социальных сетях: Facebook, Twitter, Google+, ВКонтакте.

Сам код вывода, вроде бы, здесь - http://n-wp.ru/14853, но как вывести все это - не знаю. :)